# C# stop execution until an event raises

Tags: c#, events

I need to stop execution of the program until user clicks a button. I'm doing a discrete event simulation and the goal now is to provide simple graphics illustrating the situation. When the simulation reaches an event worth showing, a method which draws the situation is called. I need the method not to jump back to the simulation core until the user clicks the button (only to be invoked again when an interesting point is reached).

Comment: This isn't a question. Please show what you have tried and where you have a problem. We aren't here to write your program for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which part of 'How to stop execution until event raises?' is not a question? Solution I could think of is sth like while(buttonnotclicked){} which wastes cpu time doing nothing.

Comment: Perhaps its just not stated well, but on my first read, I see a giant block of text that describes what you want to do. You also start off by saying "stop execution of the program", which is not something you do to a program. You might block a thread, but stopping execution would imply that even a button click would not be responded too. Overall, there isn't a clear question, and the whole thing is hard to read, confusing, and shows a lack of effort and basic understanding. Servy gave you a good answer, but its still a bad question.

Comment: What exactly do you think your/any program does before an event arises except wait for it?

Comment: @TaW Generally they do nothing.  They continue executing after wiring up a handler without waiting for anything.  Trying to wait for the asynchronous event to happen is actually non-trivial if you don't have some experience in the subject.  Of course, the OP doesn't actually want to wait, as that would block his UI, preventing the button from being clicked, indefinitely freezing the whole program.

Comment: @TaW Where are you heading?

Comment: I was trying to say that I don't understand what the OP wants beyond the normal GUI execution.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't explain it better. Servy's solution is what I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a method that will return a `Task` that will be completed when a particular button is next clicked, which it can accomplish through the use of a `TaskCompletionSource` object.  You can then `await` that task to continue executing your method when a particular button is clicked:

```
public static Task WhenClicked(this Button button)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, args) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        button.Click -= handler;
    };
    button.Click += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This enables you to write:

```
DoSomething();
await button1.WhenClicked();
DoSomethingElse();
```

Comment: THanks. Could you tell me where to put the definition? I tried putting it under Form class but that gives errors.

Comment: @MathN00b Put it in a static top level class in your project.

Comment: Had to change the method containing `await` to `async` to work. Thank you very much!